# Setup Brother MFC-465CN Multifunction Center: CUPS Server Error

Tags: drivers, printing, brother

I am absolutely new to Ubuntu (and Linux) and trying to set up a Brother MFC-465CN Multifunction Center. I went through the process of setting up the printer and used the recommended generic driver. When I tried to print a test page I got the following error:

```
There was an error during the CUPS operation: 'client-error-document-format-not-supported'.
```

Can anyone assist with this? Thanks!

Comment: Problem solved. I contacted the Brother Linux Support Team and they provided the driver and method of installation. The printer works just fine now.

Comment: I think you should post that as a self-answer. Different printer (DCP-7055) and not quite the same error message, but deleting the recommended generic driver and installed the Brother one and now it works. (It didn't work first time, though, as I didn't have cups-server package installed.)